# elastic search geo_point issue

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

In my application i am using mongoosastic . I created Mapping and schema but when i see mapping result it will change location **geo_point** property to object type so maybe for that it will give me error when i search using query:

ERROR : **nested: QueryParsingException[[userprofiles] failed to find geo_point field [location]]; }]"**

**I do query in advance rest client**

Create Mapping :

```
"mappings": {
        "userprofile": {
            "properties": {
                "address": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "timing": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "open": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "close": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

User schema

```
var UserProfileSchema = new Schema({
    userId: String,
    username: String,
    address: {
        type: String,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    number: {
        type: Number,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    location: {
        lat: Number,
        lon: Number
    },
    timing: {
        open: String,
        close: String
    }
});
```

search query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "20km",
                "location" : {
                    "lat" : 37.9174,
                    "lon" : -122.3050
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put `location` under `timing` in your mapping.

Try using this mapping instead

```
"mappings": {
        "userprofile": {
            "properties": {
                "address": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "timing": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "open": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "close": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                 "location": {
                     "type": "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```